# Tabs like in iPhone AppStore iOS 6 detail view (details, reviews, related)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tabs, app-store

Do you know any tutorial / project that implements tabs in the way that Apple did in the AppStore -> app detail page? Here is what I meant:

[image: AppStore info view tabs]

Of course I could write in by myself, but I was wondering if there isn't such think done before.

Thanks!

Comment: In what way? The button active button look? Or the partial view changing on click?

Comment: @Jeremy partial view changing on click, button active look and this small triangular intend :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/sdwellsegmentedcontrol , very useful!

Loris

Answer (score 0):

In Your case you need to create `UIView` or `UIImageView` with frame **(0, 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, 36)** and add Three `UIButton`. And set BackGround image of `UIButton` for **Both** `forState:UIControlStateNormal` and `forState:UIControlStateHighlighted`. I also write following code for You , for better understanding.

```
    UIImageView *imgHeading = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, 36)] ;
    [imgHeading setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"]];
    [self.view addSubview: imgHeading];

    UIButton *btnHome = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnHome addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnHome.frame = CGRectMake(as you need);
    [btnHome setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnHome setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:btnHome];

UIButton *btnHome1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnHome1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnHome1.frame = CGRectMake(as you need);
    [btnHome1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnHome1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:btnHome1];

UIButton *btnHome2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnHome2 addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnHome2.frame = CGRectMake(as you need);
    [btnHome2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnHome2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfImage"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:btnHome2];
```

**Thanks, may be it is helpful for you :)**